# iPhone 4S not always plays foreground app on external play command

Tags: music, alarm, iphone

I've got an older iHome iPhone dock model which, among other things, has an alarm clock feature that I use regularly with my iPhone 4S. My standard procedure for setting my alarm is this: I open the app I want to play as an alarm, then lock the phone, then put it in the dock. Most of the times, this works well: at the alarm time, the app gets the play signal from the dock, and the app in the foreground starts playing music.

However, with some web radio apps (especially bad with the app of the otherwise fantastic [Radio Paradise](http://www.radioparadise.com/rp_2.php?#)), this fails often - though not always. The app is in the foreground when I dock the phone (and stays there - no crash), when I press play on the dock just after docking to test it, the right app starts playing, but the music that starts playing in the morning is that from the phone's standard music player, even though it was not even running before.

**What could be the source of this behavior, and how can I avoid it?**

I *suspect* the following things:

- It's not relevant where the play signal comes from, be it a dock or the headset remote (though I only have experience with the dock)
- It has something to do with the delay of loading/buffering the web radio stream, and somehow the phone just handing over to the standard app after some sort of timeout

Comment: I've had similar problems with even pushing the play button on my lock screen. It may be due to the app releasing its memory after a certain amount of time, and it forgets that it was ever listening for a Play/Pause event, so the Music app gets the event a takes over.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @AndrewLarsson! Any idea how I (or the app developer, if I filed a bug report) could remedy this problem?

Comment: I think the reason has to do with it having to be online in order to get music. My best guess would be to ask the developer if UIRequiresPersistentWiFi is enabled in their info.plist for their app. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW12